# How to reduce blur or haze when shooting long distances?

Tags: image-quality, landscape, photography-basics, haze

I am new to photography any i am not sure what is the correct settings when shooting long distance landscapes.

The photo that I took is pretty blurry/hazy. Is there any specific settings or equipment to reduce this blur/haze when shooting long-distance landscapes?

Here is an example of a photo that I took.

[image: blurry/hazy cityscape]

Comment: You ask "correct setting *for* background blur", but I think from context that you want to minimize that — you'd like the landscape/cityscape to be sharp even in the distance. Is that correct?

Comment: @mattdm Yes that is correct. as you see in the pic, the bridge or the city on the right can be barely seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photo editing App [Affinity Photo](https://affinity.serif.com/en-gb/photo/) has a Haze Removal filter, which I think does a good job on some photos. Affinity Photo is available for Mac, Windows and iOS platforms. There may be similar filters in other apps. Your mileage may vary, but it's pretty amazing sometimes. I think in this case, it looks less hazy, but not a miracle cure. 
[image: Original photo after Haze Removal]

Answer (score -1):

There is not a correct answer for this. **"Correct"** is different for every shot; dictated by  camera sensor, lens, focal length, aperture, composition, atmospheric haze,  or ?

First and foremost, it is the **personal preference of the photographer**.

**I.E.** how YOU want the photo to look and that requires a *solid understanding* of what settings and factors effect depth of field in photography, taking into account all of the variable mentioned above.

Comment: Technically answers the question, but doesn't address OP's problems as clarified in comments.  There are ways to deal with the haze, none of which you mention.